# regular expression to accept only integers and decimal numbers

Tags: regex, extjs

Iam working with ext js.I have a textfield that should accept either an integer or a decimal number. Iam using regular expression to implement that. But its not working.

Here is my code...

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        id: 'myField',
        fieldLabel: 'Text Field(numbers-only)',                      
        maskRe: /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/

    }
```

While using the above regular expression, Textfield is not accepting .(dot)

How can I resolve this??

Comment: `.` in neither an integer nor a decimal.Why should it get accepted?

Comment: By "decimal" you must have meant "decimal separator", right? Remove the `$` symbol, it makes the pattern match only at the end of the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use \d* instead of \d+ before the decimal to match zero or more digits.
- Also add anchors (^ and $) or else it will pass as long as there is any match 
  available.
- This would also validate an empty string, so if necessary you can use a
  lookahead to make sure there is at least one digit:

Use Below code:

```
 {
         xtype: 'textfield',
         id: 'myField',
         fieldLabel: 'Text Field(numbers-only)',                      
         maskRe: /^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/

}
```

Per your Understanding purpose see this link [Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/17#javascript)

Comment: Neither regex pattern will validate an empty line. You have an obligatory `[1-9]` character that must be matched. The original regex has `[0-9]+`, and it will also match something.

Comment: I have checked in online that is i mentioned in above link.this is worked for   integers and decimal numbers and not for dot(.).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this if you want to limit the number of decimal places:

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

this will let you pass decimal places at least 1 but not more than 2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I well understand your need, but is this OK?

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?$/
```

This will accept:

- `123`
- `0.123`
- `123.`